# XPATH - Extract Data from elements

Tags: xpath

Following is the data and Select statement to work with :

```
declare @XMLdata xml
set @XMLdata = '
    <taggroup key="pros" name="Le pour">
      <tag isuseradded="false" count="1">Bonne qualité</tag>
      <tag isuseradded="false" count="1">Correspond à mes attentes</tag>
      <tag isuseradded="true" count="1">Impeccable</tag>
      <tag isuseradded="false" count="1">Prix abordable</tag>
    </taggroup>
    '
select      
    ParamValues.ID.value('(./@key)','nvarchar(max)') as TagGroupKey,
    ParamValues.ID.value('(./@name)','nvarchar(max)') as TagGroupName,
    ParamValues.ID.value('(./tag)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as TagValue,
from @XMLData.nodes('taggroup') as ParamValues(ID)
```

I need to extract the 4 tag values 
(`Bonne qualité`,`Correspond à mes attentes`,`Impeccable`,`Prix abordable`) 
without actually going to the tag level since that is impacting the performance.

Comment: What do you mean by "without going to the tag level"?  Also, I can't imagine how any query would have a noticeable effect on performance for a sample like this.

Comment: by "without going to the tag level" I mean : 

extract the Value of the "tag" element from the taggroup level and not access tag level at all, thus skipping for having to go through the tag level as well to get the required data .

This is just a sample data the actual data is huge!

Comment: That's sort of what I thought, but it doesn't make sense.  Your question, as far as I see it, is "how do I extract the values of some tags without extracting the values of those tags?".  I must be misunderstanding you.

Comment: Ssimply from the XML data above...  I need to extract the 4 "tag" values (mentioned above) without getting to the "tag" level...hope this is a bit more clear now :)

Comment: @Murtaza-RC: No, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are looking for, but to get all of the data under tag without the tag element itself you would use the following xpath:

```
./tag/text()
```

This (in XPATH, I am not sure about sql xml query) would return a nodeset of TEXT elements with all of the values under tag separately.  So if you had 4 tag elements, there would be four separate TEXT elements.